# Dependency Jars required for querying data from GCP Bigquery using java

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Dependency Jars required for querying data from GCP Bigquery using java.

i have to query data from gcp bigquery for that I chose java client libraries of GCP instead of REST API. I added a maven pom.xml to get the required dependencies like

```
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/libraries-bom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.17.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

It gave the 74 jars. truely all those jars required??
or any correction required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the official documentation it must be the correct numbers of jars needed for dependencies, or try this that pom content that described in the [before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#install) section of BigQuery API's reference.:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.18.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

If you scroll down a bit more you will find IDE plugins for using client libraries(that might be helpful to your use case):

> If you're using Visual Studio Code, IntelliJ, or Eclipse, you can add client libraries to your project using the following IDE plugins:
>
> - Cloud Code for VS Code
> - Cloud Code for IntelliJ
> - Cloud Tools for Eclipse